# Enabling JavaScript in Visual studio browser opened for Web Performance testing

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, load-testing, performance-testing

I am performing web performance testing for a cloud based application with AAD authentication. After recording when I am trying to replay it My visual studio browser is displaying an error that "Java Script is disabled". Is there any way to Edit the Visual Studio's Browsers setting or for Web performance testing is it possible to open the IE instead of Visual Studio browser.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that.

Visual Studio web tests do not use a browser. Visual Studio includes a very simple browser that gives an idea of the web pages etc that are retrieved. The web tests are intended to simulate the load that a browser creates, to put load onto the web server. By design Visual Studio web test facilities do not try and run JavaScript or other scripts, nor do they process .css files. They do download all such files requested by the web page.

The activity of code such as JavaScript must be simulated within your test scripts. Look at the request the JavaScript created and that Visual Studio recorded. Sometimes recording the transaction with Fiddler2 can lead to a better understanding of what the JavaScript has done. Work out which pieces of the request are set by the JavaScript and how to derive their values.

Sometimes recording two, as far as possible, indentical web tests and then comparing them as text files will help to reveal what the JavaScript has done. Sometimes comparing the recordings of two identical, but for different users, or for different application-specific items, will help.